# AzureADに登録してあるユーザー情報をJavaで取得する方法

Tags: java, azure

AzureADにテナント(ディレクトリ)を作成してそこに複数のユーザー情報を登録してあります。

質問1：
AzureADに登録してあるユーザー情報をJavaアプリケーションのユーザー情報として連携したいと考えていますがJavaでAzureADのユーザー情報を取得することは可能でしょうか？

質問2：
Javaアプリケーションのログイン画面で入力したユーザ名とパスワードの組み合わせがAzureAD上に存在するかチェックしたいのですが可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 質問1：
>   AzureADに登録してあるユーザー情報をJavaアプリケーションのユーザー情報として連携したいと考えていますがJavaでAzureADのユーザー情報を取得することは可能でしょうか？

GraphAPIを使用して可能だと思います。
[Microsoft GraphAPI](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0)

SCIMのリクエストでも可能だと思います。
https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/use-scim-to-provision-users-and-groups

> 質問2：
>   Javaアプリケーションのログイン画面で入力したユーザ名とパスワードの組み合わせがAzureAD上に存在するかチェックしたいのですが可能でしょうか？

ユーザ(ID)が存在すること　というのは確認できますが、APIを使って存在するユーザのパスワードとのセットで検索することはできません。